# MvcHtml Helper for partial of a tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I Have This:

```
public static class CustomHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ImageTag(this HtmlHelper html, Size s, string fName)
        {
            var fPath = "";
            //some other code to generate path ...

            var imgTag = new TagBuilder("img");
            imgTag.Attributes.Add("src", "~/Images/" + s.Width + "/" + s.Height + "/" + fName);

            return new MvcHtmlString(imgTag.ToString());
        }
    }
```

in markup:

```
@Html.ImageTag(new System.Drawing.Size(100,100),"test.jpg")
```

generate this:

```
<img src="~/Images/100/100/test2.jpg">
```

I want something like this:

```
<img src="@getImagePath(size(100,100),"test.jpg")">
```

In order to html tag,attributes being accessible for designer, but How?

**update:** 
Actually i want have a method to generate image path depend on it's size dynamically. but  tag being accesible for my designer.
one sulotion is create some overload for helper to get more attributes

```
public static MvcHtmlString ImageTag(this HtmlHelper html, Size s, string fName,**string cssClass**){}
```

Comment: You can't use Razor to generate more Razor (well, you *can* but that second Razor won't get executed, it'll just get written out as plain text). It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I don't want nested razor, actually i a method to generate my images path dynamically. (becusse in when web page tempalte change, i have to change my code again) need a method to get size & image name to if it doesn't exist in it's folder,like 100/100 folder, generate it in that size

Comment: Huh? So you want code to dynamically resize images? Then why have you included a load of irrelevant MVC-related fluff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an extension method for UrlHelper class:

```
public static string GetImageUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper, Size s, string fName)
{
    return urlHelper.Content("~/Images/" + s.Width + "/" + s.Height + "/" + fName);
}
```

Then use it in your view:

```
<img src="@Url.GetImageUrl(new Size(100,100),"test.jpg")">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to render this?

```
<img src="@getImagePath(size(100,100),"test.jpg")">
```

Try:

```
imgTag.Attributes.Add("src", "@getImagePath(size(" + s.Width + "," + s.Height + "),\"" + fName+"\")");
```